# Discord.py | Send an embed and edit it every 60 seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to create a discord bot that retrieves data from an API and then sends the data as a discord-embedded message. However, the information on the API changes and I want the embedded message to stay up to date by updating the message contents every 60 seconds.

The big problem is that I have other commands and the bot might send multiple messages within the 60-second period. How do I keep track of that message and edit it when needed? Can this be done by a single background task?

*Note: I don't mind using webhooks or something of the sort. I just want the job to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop). To start the loop, use `start()`. I do this with a command.

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def send_message_loop(msg):
    await msg.edit(content="World!")

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.guild.fetch_message(ID)
    send_message_loop.start(msg)
```

##### Edit

As @TheFungusAmongUs mentioned, better to pass the message as an arg instead of keeping track.

Comment: Eh, there's no point retrieving the message every loop iteration, you might as well just pass it as an argument when you start the loop.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs It's just `msg` defined there, it's not fetching anything. But yeah if you want to do that then you can pass it as an argument, but that was not asked.

Comment: It's a minor optimization but it helps since you don't have to keep track of the id - you can send the message in the start command and pass it as an arg

Comment: Mh true, edited the answer.

Comment: How would you get the 'msg' variable?

Comment: @Tony with `Guild.fetch_message`. I edited the post